# How can I pull only specific columns \ cells from csv in <pre> tag, into highcharts pie chart

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts, pre

I am new to Stack and jquery, highcharts, and a javascript novice.
I am trying to create a highcharts pie chart like this - http://jsfiddle.net/dsbvpkt0/7/
I need to however, pull the data from a csv file and only want the specific columns,

so it would look like this -

http://jsfiddle.net/techclmbr/ffkrzou3/4/
here is the .csv and code -

```
   <pre id="data.csv" class="chart" style="display:none">
```

customer,groupID,group2ID,dProcess,units,placements,collections,feePerc,liveVoxAtt,liveVoxConx,liveVoxConxFail,voAppsAtt,voAppsConx,voAppsConxFail,letterTotlSent,letter1stSing,letter1stMulti,letter2nd,letterReceipt,letter10dayPay,letterSIF,emailsNew,custGroupName
FLH01P,1,1,02/02/17,0,0,11889.39,18.5,264,17,247,53,34,19,419,411,1,5,2,0,0,7,FLH PRIMES

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'pie'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'LiveVox'                 
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            },
            series: []
        };

        // prepare csv file dummy
          var csvData = "Null,liveVoxAtt,liveVoxConx,liveVoxConxFail\nFLH01P,264,17,247";    


        // JQuery function to process the csv data

            var seriesData = [];
            var lines = csvData.split('\n');
            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                var items = line.split(',');

                if (lineNo == 0) {
                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        //skip first item of first line
                        if (itemNo > 0){
                            seriesData.push({name: item, y: 0});
                        }
                    });
                } else {

                    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                        if (itemNo > 0) {
                            seriesData[itemNo - 1]['y'] += parseFloat(item);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

options.series.push({data: seriesData, name: 'LiveVox Stats'});

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

    });
```

the data I need from the csv file is shown in the csvData variable.

So I need to be able to pull the columns and headings from the .csv in the  tag  either directly via getElemnetById() or into the csvData variable. not sure how to make it happen. Have tried many things and come close but can't seem to figure it out. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When selecting an element by id which has a dot in it you need to use "." instead of dot

```
document.getElementById("data\.csv")
```

Or if you're using jquery "\\."

```
$("data\\.csv")
```

Here is your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ffkrzou3/12/, but your split function doesn't seem to work well with the text you have in the pre tag

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that! I have played a little more with it, and can loop through the data.csv and get colums 8,9,&10 from each line of the csv, as seen by ru

Comment: Thank you Liviu for you answer. In the end, I solved my problem, see the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/techclmbr/ffkrzou3/39/

Comment: What I really needed was to pull only certain columns, from the html <pre> tag csv data. In my actual document I have 50-60 pre tags each containing 2 rows of csv data. I used a loop to pull the column data from each of the 2 rows into a string and then re-added the comma's and line break. I am sure that there is a better way to achieve what I did, just don't know how. As I said, I am new to all of this. Thank you for the response.